# Is phpDocumentor dead?

Tags: php, doxygen, phpdoc

Or is it just at a 'finished' state?   I've used PHPDoc for many years on all my PHP projects, but I recently noticed that the last post on the PHPDoc website was from 2008.  So I'm wondering if it's time to look into other alternatives like Doxygen.   Are there any advantages to using something other than PHPDoc?

EDIT:  Interesting post on Dev Zone today when Matthew announced the release of Zend Framework 1.11.5 he wrote:

"Mike van Riel offered to convert our API documentation generation to DocBlox. We'd already been considering it for ZF2, but on seeing the flexibility of the templating system, and, more importantly for us in terms of packaging, the speed and minimal resources it utilizes in generating the output, we were sold. (API documentation generation time was reduced from taking 80-100 minutes to less than 10.) You can view the results for yourself."  http://devzone.zend.com/article/13643

This is why I'm concerned, if large projects like Zend Framework are dropping phpDoc, it seems to me the inactivity of phpDoc is not going unnoticed.  100 minutes down to 10..that's what I like to hear.

@gms8994 good call

*UPDATE: So turns out DocBlox is PHPDocumentor2 in disguise/re-branded.  http://www.docblox-project.org/

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to that too. Not seen any activity from the project in a long time.  Or failing that I'd really like to know of a good alternative.

Comment: Try https://github.com/theseer/phpdox for a change.

Comment: Another alternative is [DocBlox](https://github.com/mvriel/Docblox).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is time-based. PhpDoc development has once slowed down, now it it is alive and well and some of the alternatives are struggling. In a couple of years things might be completely different. In its current state it is just confusing and/or misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently used **Doxygen** for generating documentation for PHP.This is open-source tool for documentation and support other languages too.I would say this is a good tool and it easily generate documentation as well as class diagrams and have lots of configurable features.It is available for Windows as well as UNIX/LINUX

[Can Find the latest release and DOWNLOAD Here](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

Although I currently use doxygen, too, I have to post that PHPDocumentor is not dead. Instead the attempts made by the [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/) project are joined to form the basis for [PHPDocumentor2](http://www.phpdoc.org/) which sports a brand new website. These days I'm not convinced it's production ready but it does already look really promising.

Answer (score 1):

Why fix something that isn't broken? PHPDoc works great, doesn't need anything else really. They're not trying to innovate, just to help create documentation. Which they did, very well.

Comment: Ya I get that, "if it ain't broke don't fix it" and I'm certainly down with that.  My concern, and it's not an immediate one, is what if something breaks in phpDoc with a new version of PHP (e.g. php6) or a new feature that is not supported with phpDoc, is there someone in the phpDoc community that will step up and produce a fix quickly?  And the second part to my question, I'll explain a little better, is there a must have feature that Doxygen or phpDox (or any other doc program) has that would make a compelling argument to switch?

Comment: I think enough open source projects use phpDoc that the project, or the users themselves would step up and help patch it. For example, CakePHP, which is a huge php framework and is improving daily, uses phpDoc heavily. My employer uses PhpDoc heavily, the list goes on. I know that we try to contribute to CakePHP and patching PhpDoc would be a contribution in itself.

Comment: Well, when PHP 6 comes out, then they can revive it. Until then, what's the rub?

Comment: Will they though?  It seems likely someone will but you can't say for sure.  Anyhow I'd like to see someone working on it now, if only just to try and reduce it's memory footprint.

Comment: According to Wikipedia PhpDoc ceased development in 2010 and is officially dead.  Also, as far as 'if it aint broke don't fix it' goes, well the problem is PHP isn't standing still.  PhpDoc is probably fine still for 5.2 codebases, but 5.3 introduces namespaces, late static binding, all kinds of additions to SPL and so on. Namespaces especially would probably choke PhpDoc as it doesn't understand them.

Answer (score 1):

I had several problems with phpDocumentor. One of them was the xml export. After a few attempts to fix the code I decided to look for an alternative.

What I found and liked was: Rarangi
https://bitbucket.org/laurentj/rarangi/wiki/Home

```
Rarangi is a generator of documents from php source code.
```

The interesting thing about it was that it saves the information in a mysql db and  you can make your own custom reports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @danip , like the two mentioned above it looks like it's off to a good start but again it's young and doesn't look like there's much community support yet.  I'll keep an eye on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

phpDocumentor v3 (with proper PHP 7 support) is currently alpha, getting real close to a stable release. The problem is that they don't have a lot of people working on it, so development is slow.

I've tested the latest alpha on one of my Symfony projects and it does the job okay, although it's missing some features and has a couple of bugs. They were all reported, of course.

https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/releases

**Update:** phpDocumentor v3 just went beta. Check releases.